# Dynamically attach a function to grant access to private variables

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to assign a callback dynamically to an Object of mine, I can't seem to figure out a way to do this while granting this function access to private variables.  I've listed the relavant code below with comments where I ran into walls.

### Object Factory

```
function makeObj ( o ) {
                function F() {}
                F.prototype = o;
                return new F();
            }
```

### Module

```
var MODULE = (function(){
   var myMod = {},
       privateVar = "I'm private";
   return myMod;
})();
```

### Various Attempts

---

```
myMod.someDynamicFunc = function someDynamicFunc(){
    //privateVar === undefined;
    alert( privateVar );
}
myMod.someDynamicFunc();
```

---

```
myMod.prototype.someDynamicFunc = function someDynamicFunc(){
    //ERROR: Cannot set property 'someDynamicFunc' of undefined
    alert(privateVar);
}
myMod.someDynamicFunc();
```

---

In this attempt I tried making a setter in the module object... to no avail.

```
var MODULE = (function(){
       var myMod = {},
           privateVar = "I'm private";

           myMod.setDynamicFunction = function ( func ){
              if(func !== undefined && typeof func === "function"){
                //Uncaught TypeError: 
                //         Cannot read property 'dynamicFunction' of undefined
                myMod.prototype.dynamicFunction = func;
                //also tried myMod.dynamicFunction = func;
              }
           }
       return myMod;
    })();

var myModule = makeObject( MODULE );

myModule.setDynamicFunction(function(){
   alert(privateVar);
});

myModule.dynamicFunction();
```

---

Am I just using JavaScript wrong? I'd really like to be able to assign callbacks after the object is initiated.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the private variable via a callback function set dynamically (since it can't be a closure if it's attached later), but you can set up a system by which you would be able to access the variable:

```
var MODULE = (function(){
   var myMod = {},
       privateVar = "I'm private";

   myMod.callback = function(fn) {fn(privateVar);};

   return myMod;
})();

var someDynamicFunc = function(param) {alert(param);};
myMod.callback(someDynamicFunc);
```

Of course, this makes it not really private, since anyone could do this. I don't see how it would be possible at all for you to have a "private" variable that you access via dynamically attached functions, without allowing anyone else's dynamically attached functions to have the same privilege (thus making it not really private).

Comment: good point... it looks like i just have to send these callbacks in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you did not really understand exactly how closures work.

Closures mean that scopes *always* have access to the outer scope they were **defined** in.

```
function Counter(start) {
    var count = start;


    return {
        increment: function() { // has access to the outer scope
            count++;
        },

        get: function() {
            return count;
        }
    }
}

var foo = new Counter(4);
foo.increment();
foo.get(); // 5
```

The above example  returns **two closures**, both the function `increment` as well as `get` keep a reference to the `count` variable defined in the constructor.

One **cannot** access `count` from the outside, the only way to interact with it is via the two "closured" functions.

Remember, closures work by keeping a reference to their outer scopes, so the following does **not** work:

```
var foo = new Counter(4);
foo.hack = function() { // is not getting defined in the same scope that the original count was
    count = 1337;
};
```

This will **not** change the variable `count` that's inside of `Counter` since  `foo.hack` was **not defined** in that scope, instead, it will create or override the global variable `count`.